# Python weird answer (tuple and list with count function)

Tags: python, iterator, python-3.7

This is the code given below.

```py
k = [1, 8, 15]
g = (x for x in k if k.count(x) > 0)
k = [2, 8, 22]
print(list(g))
```

I am getting the output as [8] but it should be [1,8,15], right? since each element is present at least once.

Any plausible explanation for the answer?

Answer (score 9):

That's a [generator expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0289/). It creates a generator, not a tuple.

Exactly one part of a generator expression is evaluated at genexp creation time. It's this part:

```
g = (x for x in k if k.count(x)>0)
#               ^
```

Everything else, including this part:

```
g = (x for x in k if k.count(x)>0)
#                    ^
```

is evaluated lazily.

That means the `k` you're looping over is the original `k`, but the `k` you're calling `count` on is the new `k`.

Comment: Is it related to this that you showed in generator expression. I found this quote right there: 
"After much discussion, it was decided that the first (outermost) for-expression should be evaluated immediately and that the remaining expressions be evaluated when the generator is executed." So in the case you are telling is it reads the first k however when the value of K changes the second part of the generator also changes as well?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a trick to see which `k` uses the original/modified list by printing `x` and `k` in the generator expression:

1st `k` refers to the original list:

```py
>>> k = [1,8,15]
>>> g = (x for x in k if (print(x) == None and k.count(x)>0))
>>> k = [2,8,22]
>>> list(g)
1
8
15
```

2nd `k` refers to the modified list:

```py
>>> k = [1,8,15]
>>> g = (x for x in k if (print(k) == None and k.count(x)>0))
>>> k = [2,8,22]
>>> list(g)
[2, 8, 22]
[2, 8, 22]
[2, 8, 22]
```

Comment: Shorter: `if print(k) or k.count(x)>0`

Answer (score 3):

Debugging trick similar to Shawn's:

```
def p(label, x):
    print(label, x)
    return x

k = [1,8,15]
g = (x for x in p('iterate over', k) if p('count in', k).count(x)>0)
k = [2,8,22]
print('between generator construction and consumption')
list(g)
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3NCsIwEAbveYq9pYEgtiIUQV9EeujPWkPrJqQbjU8f0/bg3mZY5nNfflo61c6nNOADXDG3Hc4aoroIyOe8If7LzXnk4AmiEBNc4V7qWpfnRowZiggP6yGCodyShtG3jGDf6KWGSYFZN2RvA3H@2dxhoyKq21HtxSoXq6oR@7jskD@IBCPSmsv93tLCPvRsLEFLwybCy60slZjNwsWoUvoB)):

```
iterate over [1, 8, 15]
between generator construction and consumption
count in [2, 8, 22]
count in [2, 8, 22]
count in [2, 8, 22]
```

Answer (score -2):

Generator is fetch on process memory,work like lazy operator so that happen

"""""for x in [1,8,15]:
if [2,8,22].count(x):  """"
That is how interpreter fetch values.

Refer this tweet for more understand:

https://twitter.com/nedbat/status/1503735148378001410?t=lJLT482Vmt19cBNuP-PAWQ&s=19

https://twitter.com/driscollis/status/1503366898234404866?t=OgCM0E1rzWAEQOOziO9uqA&s=19

#Learning with hope